# Angular - Making an API call for ng-hide/show - Bad idea?

Tags: angularjs

I have a button that i want to show/hide depending on whether a user has posted on an item before. To find this out I've written an API call which returns true or false.

However whenever I use this is my code, I keep getting the:

`Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` error.

Why would my code be doing this and is the general way I've implemented this the correct way to go about this?

My code looks like:

```
<div ng-show='main.hasPosted()'>The Button To Go In Here</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
self.hasPosted = function() {
      $http.get(API + '/hasPosted', {
         headers: {
           itemtocheck: $routeParams.id
         }
       }).
       then(function(result){
         return result.data.success;
});
```

Comment: That's because your hasPosted()  function is under unresolved state. Try using a $scope variable and use that for comparison

Comment: This is  terrible approach having view making `$http` requests. Will make a request every digest and there can be many digests within one cycle

Comment: Thanks Coder John - thats it. And makes sense to me

Comment: charlie tfl - can you kindly suggest another way to do this?

Comment: Make one request only in controller and assign result to a model property

Comment: Thanks Charlie but I'm still unsure how I'd implement that approach. When you say one request in the controller I could do that fine but don't understand the assign result to model property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-show='showButton'>The Button To Go In Here</div>

self.hasPosted = function() {
      $http.get(API + '/hasPosted', {
         headers: {
           itemtocheck: $routeParams.id
         }
       }).
       then(function(result) {
$scope.showButton = result.data.success;
});
```

Comment: Thanks - makes sense using a scope variable.  however at what point do I call the hasPosted function itself for that div?

Comment: You can make it the very first call as soon as the controller is initialised. Or depending upon your business logic what suits better!

Comment: Cool - all works now. And btw - do you/can you help me with understanding Charlietfl's comment above - i'm curious to know as naturally want to code to be written the best way possible.

Comment: Just to summarise what Charlietfl is saying that to achieve two way data binding some core functions of Angular libraries are called, which are resource consuming, but with the above implementation this would not matter now. Still for detailed explanation you can further read: https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/ . Thanks